# Where is the documentation for perf events?

Tags: linux, profiling, perf-event

I cant seem to find documentation on the events listed when you do `perf list`; can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601474/what-are-perf-cache-events-meaning

Comment: You can look at this [answer][1] to the same question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520711/performance-counter-information-required/15648243#15648243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PMU Hardware events documentation is specific to the processor manufacturer:

- Intel: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.pdf
- AMD: http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/31116.pdf